# $.getJSON returning “undefined” or [object Object] [object Object]

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, httphandler, getjson

I know there are some people who asked same question and get answered. I already looked ino all of them, still I couldn't solve my issue. I am having a jquery snipet which send value to a handler and the handler process the value from JS and returns data as JSON data. JSON data has two sets of records( two rows from database) which need to be catch through getJSON and process that. 
JSON data will look like

```
[{"Name":"P1","Description":"pd1",Value":"S1Test1"},{"Name":"P1","Description":"pd1","Value":"L1Test1"}]
```

My JS is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('ProfileHandler.ashx', { 'ProfileName': 'P1' }, function (data) {
        alert(data.Name);
    });
});
```

and my handler code is

```
string ProfileName = context.Request["ProfileName"];
GetProfileDataService GetProfileDataService = new BokingEngine.MasterDataService.GetProfileDataService();
IEnumerable<ProfileData> ProfileDetails = GetProfileDataService.GetList(new ProfileSearchCriteria { Name = ProfileName });
JavaScriptSerializer javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string serProfileDetails = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(ProfileDetails);
context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
context.Response.Write(serProfileDetails);
```

What is the approach error here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`data` is an array of objects

```
data[0].name
```

should be enough to fetch the first name.

To iterate over the entire array, you could do something like:

```
$.each(data, function(k, v){
    alert(v.name);
});
```

Where `v` is the current object in the array. Note that `v == this`

Comment: You gave me more than what I asked, Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON defines an *array*, which has objects as entries. So instead of

```
alert(data.Name);
```

you'd want

```
alert(data[0].Name);
```

(and of course, other indexes as well, in your example you have `0` and `1`).

*(The quoted JSON is also invalid [missing `"` before the first `Value`], but I'm guessing that's a typo in the question.)*